# Fetch data when building for production, Angular

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular application that needs to get some data from a server, the data is not changing very often so I don't want to make a request every time someone loads the application, I would rather make a call every time I build the app and have it as part of the bundle.

So my question is: is there a way to fetch data from a server when building, and using it in the application? (and for serving in dev mode it should maybe fetch on each build)

Comment: Check: shareReplay of rxjs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Angular Universal` prerendering. It's quite complex to describe in one short answer, but you can start exploring for instance from this tutorial:  [Angular Universal: Pre-Rendering with renderModuleFactory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6CKlV7kGVM)